# Call to a member function connection() on a non-object

Tags: model, eloquent, slim, pagination

I'm developing an API with slim 3. I'm trying to use fractals paginate() but I keep getting an error because of the model, I guess. I've been researching all over google an still didn't found an answer that suits my problem.

Here is model:

```
class wholesalers extends Model {

    protected $table = 'tbl_wholesalers';

}
```

my controller:

```
try {
    $fractal = new Manager();
    $fractal->setSerializer(new DataArraySerializer());
    #$wholesalers = $this->db->table('tbl_wholesalers')->select('*')->get();
    $paginator = wholesalers::paginate();
    $wholesalers = $paginator->getCollection();

    if ($wholesalers) {
        $resource = new Collection($wholesalers, new wholesalersTrans);
        $resource->setPaginator(new \League\Fractal\Pagination\IlluminatePaginatorAdapter($paginator));
        $data = $fractal->createData($resource)
            ->toArray();

        $final = $response->withStatus(200)
                ->withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                ->write(json_encode($data['data'], JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));

        $this->logger->info('Wholesalers viewed with success.');

        return $final;
    } else {
        $this->logger->error('No wholesalers found!');
        return $response->withStatus(404)
                        ->write('No wholesalers found!');
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $this->logger->error($e->getMessage());
}
```

And the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function connection() on a non-object in ***/vendor/illuminate/database/Eloquent/Model.php on line 3280
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Does not look like you are connecting to Eloquent. You should be constructing Eloquent somewhere in your code.

Comment: I am. In my dependecies.php 
`$container['db'] = function ($c) {
    $capsule = new \Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager;
    $capsule->addConnection($c['settings']['db']);
    $capsule->setAsGlobal();
    $capsule->bootEloquent();

    return $capsule;`

Comment: Do you have PDO Installed?

Comment: Okay... but you need to make sure PDO is installed and configured on your server where you are running this.

Comment: I am having the same issue, but with PDO installed. If you have a solution now, I would like to know it. Thanks

Comment: Make sure both the PDO and PDO-MYSQL package exists and is turned on in your PHP.ini file. You can check the status by inpecting the output of  <?php phpinfo();    ... if not stop by the Slim Slack or IRC Channel and I can possibly help you